# How much cargo did the Nostromo carry in her decks?

Tags: alien-franchise

The Nostromo was a transport tug. How much capacity did it have given in was a multi year mission?

Comment: I thought it was transporting iron ore.

Comment: Not according to the novelisation

Comment: Enough to vaporize an entire franchise...

Comment: @Machavity - Aliens was the superior film. It was so good, it's *still* convincing the studio that they can make a worthy sequel, all evidence to the contrary.

Comment: @Valorum "*a worthy sequel*" -- [or six](http://www.smh.com.au/entertainment/movies/ridley-scott-promises-a-return-to-alienstyle-horror-in-alien-covenant-20170222-guj8wk.html), heh. *"If you really want a franchise, I can keep cranking it for another six..."*

Comment: A tug doesn't typically carry cargo itself, it _tugs_ other vessels which may carry cargo.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The original script indicates that the Nostromo was acting as a tug, pulling a refinery that contains two *billion* tons of "mineral ore". During the journey, that ore would be processed by [the refinery](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/143350/20774) into oil products such as petroleum.

> **EXT. NOSTROMO**
>
> The Factory Starship lumbering with the depths of inter-stellar space.
>
> Function:           Petroleum tanker and Refinery.
>   Capacity:           **2000,000,000 tons.**
>   Length:             One and one half kilometers.
>
> Battered exterior encrusted with dark sludge.
>
> <sup><sup>[Alien: Shooting Script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/alien_shooting.html)</sup></sup>

---

Interestingly, in the novelisation, "Two billion tons" is described as the *total tonnage of the refinery **and its cargo***.

> Her gaze rose to the rear-facing screen. A small point of light
>   silently turned into a majestic, expanding fireball sending out
>   tentacles of torn metal and shredded plastic. **It faded, was followed
>   by a much larger fireball as the refinery went up. Two billion tons of
>   gas and vaporized machinery filled the cosmos,** obscured her vision
>   until it, too, began to fade.
>
> <sup><sup>[Alien: Official Novelisation](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_(novel))</sup></sup>

This tallies better with the opening of the film in which the cargo is described as ***"20,000,000 tons of mineral ore"***. Presumably the refinery itself weighs rather more.

[image]

Comment: **a much larger fireball as the refinery went up**. A refinery explosion in outer space sadly will be a damp squib. Better not be nearby or your ship will see its exterior ruined with ugly oil and tar spots rapidly freezing and hardening on your well-maintained outer hull. Removing those could cost lots of galactocreds at the nearest W-Y drydocks. Unless you have W-Y "antioil" insurance.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Except, surely the oil and tar spots would sublime away over time?

Comment: More likely errors, sorry. It is possible the 2 billion tons are right - and the weight of the Nostromo is a rounding error.

Comment: The problem with 2 billion tons of oil is that its density is about 1, for a volume of 2E9 m^3, and the length is only 1.5km ... for a frontal area approaching 1.5e6 m^2, say 1 x 1.5km x 1.5km long, practically a cube. At the other extreme, a density of about 10 (uranium ore?) would still give a frontal area of 1.5e5m, or about 400m x 400m (x 1.5km long). All of which allows nothing for interior space, where action can happen. 20 million tons is much more in line with a current oil tanker, scaled up 4-fold in each dimension.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - All of the action in the film takes place in the tiny ship at the front, not the refinery behind.

Comment: From the novelisation (which I read about 30 years ago...) I recall something like "they no longer needed the oil for fuel, but humanity could live without energy more easily than they could live without plastics."

Comment: @MikeHarris - "*Fusion and solar power ran all of man's machines. But they couldn't substitute for petrochemicals. A fusion engine could not produce plastics, for example. The modern worlds could exist without power sooner than they could without plastics. Hence the presence of the Nostromo's commercially viable, if historically incongruous, cargo of machinery and the noisome black liquid it patiently processed.*"

Answer (score 23):

The *Nostromo* has the following capacity according to the script of *Alien*:

> CAPACITY. 200 000 000 TONNES

As the other answer says, in the movie this is changed to "cargo" and 20 000 000 tonnes, implying the actual cargo is that heavy.

That said, it's not transporting crude oil per se. Ripley, from the script:

> This is commercial towing vehicle Nostromo out of the Solomons, registration number one-eight-oh-niner-two-four-six-oh-niner.

The *Nostromo* is a towing vehicle, or hauler, which is transporting an oil *refinery*. The *Nostromo* itself is the small ship that lands on LV-426:

[image]

This huge thing is the refinery it's towing:

[image]

We don't know how much oil it holds.

Comment: @DoctorTwo Valorum's answer is better IMO!

Comment: "This huge thing is the refinery it's towing:" Phew, I finally understand (and I can rest in peace): all these years I was wondering "How the hell the (remaining) crew intended to seek and capture the Xenomorph on such big ship???"

Answer (score 1):

Of course it could also be carrying 200 million tonnes.

[image: Screen showing 200 million tonnes capacity]