# Why does Weyland Yutani want a xeno for weapon when they have, for example, androids?

Tags: alien-franchise, plot-device, xenomorph

I could see xenos being useful from a medical standpoint but in a time when technology includes not just FTL drives but also controllable androids, what could xenos do as a weapon that would be useful?

Comment: This group isn't intended for opinions or speculative answers, Even so, one obvious answer is that xenomorphs can reproduce rapidly in enemy territory at no cost to the attacker.

Comment: I don't think WY want the alien as a weapon, so much as that studying could lead to more useful weapons *in general*. The armour, rapid growth, molecular acid, etc are all things that can be deployed into other weapons such as guns, biological entities and androids.

Comment: Plus wiping out a colony or planet with thousands or millions of androids would attract a lot of unwanted attention (not to mention expensive). Dropping a single alien egg onto a planet would be sufficient to wipe it out in most cases.

Comment: @Valorum: My bigger question is that the need for weapons at all seems very old-fashioned in a civilization that should not experience scarcity. What is a plausible reason for killing a bunch of human consumers? Especially using a virtually uncontrollable "weapon?"

Comment: @releseabe - I'm not sure we could say that the civilisation WY operate in is post-scarcity. Technologically it may be possible for it to be so, but with such a powerful corporation having so much sway, scarcity could be and probably is manufactured.

Comment: @releseabe - What makes you think that a world in which they need to transport oil from one place to another (and where people get paid for their labour) is post-scarcity?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins: I foresee androids as either making life better for everyone or causing extreme marginalization for humans whose jobs are taken by such androids. Then I guess such humans literally take up space which the ultrarich want. And maybe that is what xenomorphs could be helpful with.

Comment: @Valorum: Where do we see oil being transported?

Comment: @releseabe - The [Nostromo](https://alienanthology.fandom.com/wiki/USCSS_Nostromo) is a flying oil refinery

Comment: The same reason Umbrella keeps releasing zombie plagues to collect "combat data".

Comment: @Valorum Nostromo was a star freighter that hauled an ore refinery, not an oil refinery.

Comment: @Legion600 - The "Nostromo Refinery"; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143299/whats-the-name-of-the-refinery-being-pulled-by-the-nostromo

Comment: Alien eggs seem to be mostly free. Prometheus seems to suggest they are fire and forget weapons.  I imagine an android being rather expensive in comparison.

Comment: @Valorum According to the picture you posted here, it was mineral ore. Perhaps shale ore  then.  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154723/how-much-cargo-did-the-nostromo-carry-in-her-decks

Comment: Remember when the Alien Queen ripped Bishop in half in _Aliens_? Seems like the xenomorphs might be worth looking into.

Comment: "What is a plausible reason for killing a bunch of human consumers?" — Who says they need weapons to kill humans? The marines in _Aliens_ don't act as if the very existence of alien life, or their mission to go kill some of it, is a surprise. Presumably in interstellar expansion, weapons to kill aliens are pretty handy too.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: That's a point -- they might want to use xenos (or some technology derived from studying them) not to kill humans but other alien life forms (which we have sort of seen if you count Predators and Engineers. We also hear the term "bug hunt" in Aliens).

Answer (score 26):

For the original movies, the company doesn't know precisely what the Aliens are all about. But they know enough to casually risk the lives of innocents, in the hopes that they will obtain some useful advantage.

*Alien*: Special Order 937 told Ash to "investigate a life form, possibly hostile and bring it back for observation." Maybe they haven't told Ash everything they know, but the sense is that they've underestimated the dangers. It would be ludicrous to send an uninformed freighter crew to pick up a xenomorph otherwise. And note that Ash is not trying to kill everybody, he just wants to bring the alien back, and the crew is regarded as expendable - even when W-Y doesn't know what a prize the alien really is.

*Aliens*: Years later, and as a result of learning about the events of the first film, the company knows a lot more about the xenomorphs, and they've positively decided that retrieving them would be worth "millions" to their bio-weapons division. This justifies (in their eyes) the sacrifice of random civilians and a military team. Once again, though, they've underestimated the dangers present - though if anything that makes the xenomorphs seem even more useful!

At *this* point, the company knows that a single xenomorph has absurd capabilities in hand-to-hand combat and survival. The infestation from a small number of eggs was bad enough that (the survivors of) an elite squad of Colonial Marines wanted to nuke the site from orbit as their best option. This suggests that even as-is, the aliens are a terror weapon that outmatch conventional military capabilities. And although some of the subsequent media in the franchise has military androids, what we see of Ash and Bishop does not seem to put them on the same danger level as the xenomorphs; Bishop has some knife skills but the alien can rip him apart.

But ultimately, Weyland-Yutani is the kind of company that is quite happy to throw away other people's lives for the sake of profit, or even a chance at profit. It doesn't need to be the case that they have carefully assessed how to integrate xenomorph-derived knowledge into their technology, or carried out an analysis of android vs. alien capabilities. They saw a chance and they went for it.

In *Alien Resurrection* we do see the kind of thing they were able to accomplish, aiming to create a super-soldier. And in other subsequent media, not just films, we see a lot of variations of aliens and androids, and get to learn more about them. This is how expanded media ends up. But Weyland-Yutani's motivations make sense on the level of the original story, where we don't have all of those details but do understand that W-Y are assholes.

Comment: Is there any actual confirmation in Aliens or subsequent works that WYs actions are anything but Burke thinking he can get a huge payout and manipulating the situation?  Ie a middle manager getting ideas above his station?  I mean, if it was WY as an official act to pursue the life form, surely they would have acted sooner than picking Ripley up 70 years later…

Comment: I think the film is not clear about it. He is evidently pretty senior, to be able to arrange the mission, but nobody talks about other senior company people either way. From Alien 3 and Resurrection it does seem like he's not the only bad apple in the good ol' Weyland-Yutani barrel.

Comment: I think Resurrection can be discounted - its far off in the future and the experiments are now heavily influenced by the military.  But my take on Alien3 is that WY is still very much being opportunistic - the recovery ship is prioritised when the convicts inform WY of Ripleys condition, but they were still sending a recovery ship before that point anyway (there was no "shut her up" before then, and they left the convicts alone afterward...).  WY does want to get hold of the alien, but I think it would be a gold mine for most corporations anyway.

Comment: The xenomorphs really aren't that extraordinary a weapon.  With better intelligence, the Colonial marines in *Aliens* could have easily - trivially - handled them.  In classic action sci-fi horror movie fashion, they have to be given a situational advantage ("You can't use your real weapons near the fusion equipment!") to make them competitive.  In the open field with artillery and air support, the xenomorphs would be as endangered as spotted owls.

Comment: @tbrookside Every weapon has weak points. By your logic no weapon is extraordinary since there exists one or more situations in which every weapons is outmatched by other, more suitable weapons. Also, good luck hitting even a lone human-form xenomorph with artillery, let alone one of the canine variants 

Comment: @tbrookside they are an excellent populace clearing tool - give them a few weeks, all the populace is gone.  Give it another few years, nothing but eggs - send in a trained cleanup squad, then move your people in to occupy.

Comment: @tbrookside Marines take years to train and significant resources to outfit. Xenomorphs go from newly hatched to lethal maturity in a matter of hours, need very little care and feeding and can be grown as quickly as you can procure warm bodies to cultivate the eggs in.

Comment: I agree with @Moo, they are very cheap "planet killers". No matter what capabilities they have, androids are not easy to develop, build or maintain. Look at nowadays robtoics, they are extreme complicated and really expensive. If you imagine a fully automated assembly line for androids / robots some day in the future, they would be far more superior / complicated than today's car assembly lines, and those belog to the biggest industry of our time with millions of people required to work in it to be productive!

Comment: I suddenly imagined a strain of xenomorph who implanted in an owl, and can now not only fly but also turn their heads all the way around.

Answer (score 0):

### Xenomorphs can replicate themselves, quickly and without extra effort

Xenomorphs can replicate themselves very fast and without any supply or effort (unless you count the effort spent on eliminating their victims). Androids might be able to produce more androids using resources of the enemy (if the necessary high-tech parts are available), but the time and effort spent on replicating is time and effort lost for the main objective. Also, creating an android likely takes more time than a xenomorph needs to fully grow -- and by then the xenomorph has already killed *several* victims.

The advantage of androids is that they are able to be given other objectives than "kill and multiply" and that they can adapt their objectives to the circumstances, ask for new objectives, or simply give up an impossible mission. So if you want controlled destruction and goal-oriented problem solving, an android is probably the better choice. But if you want to wreak havoc, send a xenomorph.

There are other weapons of mass destruction, but at least in comparison to known and existing examples, xenomorph again have qualities that may make them the preferable choice. In particular, none of the existing nuclear, chemical, or biological weapons will actively hunt its prey, while xenomorphs do exactly that. Even protective gear will succumb, if not to the raw violence, then to the notorious acid.

Also, creating and deploying the currently known weapons of mass destruction can become costly and time-consuming, if a larger area is to be affected, whereas xenomorphs spread  out and deploy themselves. Current biological weapons can also propagate, but they need a host for that. Propagation by wind or water dilutes microorganisms, so isolation works against them -- against xenomorphs, not so much.

Finally, cleaning up after widespread use of weapons of mass destruction is impossible, or at least not sensible. Removing xenomorphs after usage seems doable, as long as no new prey becomes available (e.g. using androids or remotely controlled drones). Moreover, if a xenomorph-specific pathogen can be found, cleaning up xenomorphs is a piece of cake compared to cleaning up nuclear, chemical, or microbial contamination.

Comment: Yes, I think xenos would extremely effective at wiping out an enemy but the clear remaining issue is now the planet is infested with a very dangerous and possibly much worse enemy. And if all you want to do is kill everyone, why, we had weapons that would do that since the h-bomb 70 years ago. Or the neutron bomb. So again, I just don't find xenos as weapons very compelling. I think they could have come up with something more creative and plausible than this.

Comment: @releseabe: You asked about xenos vs. androids, not xenos vs. weapons of mass destruction. But even in that comparison, xenos have advantages: Xenos do not affect plant life or smaller animals, buildings may need to be renovated, but will remain mostly intact, and one xenomorph may be sufficient to ruin a whole civilisation. Achieving the same with H-bombs or better cobalt bombs would be unlikely to be cost-effective (to use Burke-speak). Cleaning up after xenomorphs may be costly, if no specific pathogen can be found, but cleaning up widespread radioactive contamination is impossible.